# powerbi report with ssrs does not work on web application

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, powerbi

I have an on-promise server and published a sample powerbi report on SSRS, then I called the report inside reportviewer control (in my asp web application), but I am getting below error, can any one please help me with it?

> The operation you are attempting on item '/XXXX' is not allowed for
>   this item type. (rsWrongItemType)،

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete,  and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Report Viewer Control only suports paginated rdl reports. If you are using SSRS preview with Power BI support the best option for embedding is an iFrame.

Comment: what about opening the url from reportserver directly? I mean "http://serveername/reportserver/reportname", I have same error. it seems SSRS does not render the report.